# Elastic Search- How exactly is search_after better than primitive pagination(from and size)?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have a requirement where I need to page through a big set of results. Now, I understand how primitive paging is not a good idea here considering that if I have to search let's say 10th Page, elastic search would have to load all 10 pages in memory, sort them and then aggregate to give the results which is not an ideal situation.

However, when using search after, we provide the last sorted value from first page and we basically tell elastic search - "**Give me results which are beyond this field**". My question here is how is this performant? As I understand it is the same as adding a new filter to your original query which says that next set of results should have the sort value greater than last page. Is that all that's there to it or is there something more that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

To make it short, normal pagination with `from/size` will always need to keep track of all hits from the `from` parameter of the very first request (i.e. increasing with each new pagination).

Whereas, using `search_after` it is not necessary to do so as the amount of data to keep track of is only as big as the `size` parameter (i.e. constant with each pagination).

If you want to dig into more details, I suggest you have a look at the following tickets:

- [#4940: Improve scroll search by using Lucene's IndexSearcher#searchAfter](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/4940)
- [#8192: Search: Expose Lucene's searchAfter in the search API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8192)
- [#16125: Add search_after parameter in the SearchAPI](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/16125)